# Cloudant docker image does not load from persisted volume

Tags: docker, cloudant

I'm using the `cloudant-developer` image, and am running into troubles with persisting the data.

Specifically, when running the image, I have a persistent volume that is used to store the DB:
`docker volume create cloudant-volume`

Then when running it, I use
`docker run -d -v cloudant-volume:/srv --name cloudant-container -p 8094:80 --hostname cloudant.dev ibmcom/cloudant-developer:2.0.1`

The first time I do this, going to the dashboard (i.e. localhost:8094/dashboard.html) will let me login, and then I'll see a list of 3 default databases.

However, when I then stop the container, and then start it again - using the same volume - and not deleting it in between - I go to the dashboard and just get an empty list of databases.

I've also tried to look around in the container to see if I can find logs but haven't had any luck with it. Any chance somebody else has had the same issue and solved it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the cloudant docker image to check where it persists it's data and made sure you're matching that wirh your volume?

Comment: Ya. Followed the dockerhub instructions `https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/cloudant-developer/`, which are where I got the `/srv` endpoint from.